# 19 Threads for WPF Application

Tags: wpf

I just created a new WPF application which has about 5 windows and makes use of the Xceed Data Grid. After looking in the task manager I saw that this small application had 19 threads running.

Can this be correct? I expected the WPF framework to use 2-3 threads, but not 19.
Or am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: That's pretty much just how it goes with any windows app.  10 is almost the bare minimum if you are showing a form.

Comment: What does a form need with 10 threads?  It needs one for the message pump.  What are the other 9 for?

Comment: That does sound very odd. I would expect two threads for a regular app with additional threads for background workers etc, but not 19.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**First, it isn't 19.**

When running a "Hello, World!" WPF app, I see 10 threads in Task Manager.  When running the same app using the Visual Studio debugger, it uses 19. So, first, factor out 9 of these added as overhead from the debugger.

**Now for the 10**.

According to a MSDN Magazine article called ["Build More Responsive Apps With The Dispatcher"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163328.aspx), WPF starts out with two threads:

> All WPF applications start out with
>   two important threads, **one for rendering** and **one for managing the user interface**. The rendering thread
>   is a hidden thread that runs in the
>   background, so the only thread that
>   you ordinarily deal with is the UI
>   thread.

But according to [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/alejacma/archive/2009/08/10/managed-debugging-with-windbg-threads-part-2.aspx), there are lots of basic threads in all managed apps, WPF or not:

> There are different types of .NET
>   threads: finalizer, GC, debugger,
>   timer, threadpool, primary and
>   background threads. But not all
>   threads related to .NET are managed.

Starting with the **two** from WPF, add in the GC and the finalizer to get up to **four**.  Add in the debugger thread (all managed apps have one even when not debugging) to get to **five**.  Add the timer to get to **six**.

And, attaching a debugger to my WPF app after starting it outside VS, I can see there are two worker threads in the thread pool.  This is likely a minimum.  This gets my app up to **eight**.

There are two I cannot account for exactly, but they are likely COM threads for interop (they are definitely not managed threads).  The [second article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163328.aspx) I referenced discusses more of these.

But the real moral of the story here is, don't worry about them.  If a vanilla "Hello, World!" app uses 10, that is your baseline.  **Only worry about threads you create beyond this minimum.**