# Why so many threads are created for a simple WPF application

Tags: wpf, multithreading

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [19 Threads for WPF Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1484060/19-threads-for-wpf-application)

I just created a simplest WPF application with just a window and grid and nothing else inside, not a single line of code. On my system this application is creating 16 threads. I am curious to know why WPF application creates so many threads for simplest task? Does it creates any performance issues?
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it might be thread pool WPF actively uses, threads are not actually in active use.

Comment: aloneguid: Does that means these threads will not be affecting my application's performance at all?

Comment: @Vibhore Tanwer: Exactly. By design thread pool threads are dormant (suspended) until some work is passed to them.

Comment: Tudor : Thanks for your help, I was just digging into some performance issues and thought this might be some problem.