# Concurrency Visualizer - Understanding WPF/CLR threading

Tags: .net, wpf, multithreading, clr

I've been using the Concurrency Visualizer tool in Visual Studio to get an understanding of the threading in a WPF project I'm working on. The application isn't heavily multi-threaded, all multi-threading is just to avoid blocking the UI Thread. When I ran the Concurrency Visualizer I was very surprised to see approximately 50+ threads! To make things more confusing, almost all of those 50+ threads, spent their entire time in "Synchronization", which is "blocked" as far as I understand.

As an experiment I created a new blank WPF Application project, and ran it with the Concurrency Visualizer, again to my surprise, an application that I expected to have a single main thread, and maybe one or two more for garbage collection or other CLR stuff, turns out to have 10 threads!

[image: Screenshot of Concurrency Visualizer showing 10 threads in a simple WPF Application]

So my questions are:

1. Why are there so many threads in a very simple application?
2. Generally speaking what are the functions of these threads?
3. Why are they spending almost all their time "Synchronization"?
4. Any recommendations for a book/website that covers this topic?

Answer (score 0):

There is a good answer for that question here, by Jerry Bullard: [19 Threads for WPF Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1484060/19-threads-for-wpf-application)

So, besides of WPF UI and rendering threads, there are different types of .NET threads: finalizer, GC, debugger, timer, threadpool, primary and background threads. Threadpool have minimum of two threads. This all gives us a minimum of 10 threads (just like in your screenshoot).