# Does the WriteableBitmap initialization start some background thread?

Tags: c#, wpf, writeablebitmap

I don't know if I need to give more information but I have been browsing through my code and I couldn't find anything else that causes this problem.

I have a `WriteableBitmap` somewhere inside my code that I only declare via `WriteableBitmap wb;`

Now giving only that information, when I now close the main window, the debugging process in VS 2013 stops and everything seems to be fine.
However, when I initialize `wb` as in

```
wb = new WriteableBitmap(dimx, dimy, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Indexed8, paletteGray);
```

not running any other line of code afterwards and then close the window, VS doesn't seem to stop debugging, meaning I have to click on the "stop" button to stop everything running, which also takes a long time (up to 15 seconds) after I initialize `wb`.

Is there maybe anything I am missing about `WriteableBitmap` here?

Comment: I'd say no, as I can't reproduce this behaviour. There must be some other part of your application that causes it. Did you check at all if the thread count increases when you create the WriteableBitmap?

Comment: I have checked before and after initializing wb using `Process.GetCurrentProcess().Threads.Count`. Before initializing wb I get 30 and right afterwards I get 31 so it looks like a thread is being created, but I honestly don't understand what for and how to deal with it.
In addition why are there 30 threads running?

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1484365/1136211).

Comment: Thank you, that answers the large thread count. But I have still no idea why initializing wb opens a new thread that remains after closing the window...

Comment: Even if a thread is created upon creation of a WriteableBitmap, that would not explain why terminating the application takes 15 seconds.

Comment: I will look further where this problem might come from and post an answer if I find one.

Comment: WriteableBitmap does not directly create threads during construction; but, it does call into some native code during construction--who knows what happens in there...

Comment: What about code that initializes values dimx, dimy, paletteGray? Creating any threads there?

Comment: @sthotakura There is one possible problem I have found and I might update the question for that. I have many objects that each have one `WriteableBitmap` but they all use the same `paletteGray` so I only create it once being a static member and that might cause a problem.